# Installing PECL OAuth (PHP) in WAMP environment

Tags: php, oauth, wamp, pecl

I would like to install PECL OAuth, but I don't know where to begin.  Where do I put the files contained in the zip?  Do I place them all in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext with the .dll files?

If anyone has experience installing PECL OAuth, I could really use some help!

Thank you.

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php

Comment: Thanks - I'm still confused.  I need to install OAuth to implement the LinkedIn API.  I've downloaded the PECL OAuth library, as linked to from the LinkedIn API site, but I'm not sure what to do next.  I did read that site, Mike, but I'm still unsure.  Thanks for your patience.